# Is that the correct password?

Tags: python, passwords

I want to write a piece of code that will check if the password submitted is correct. Let's say the password is programmingisfun.

I've been at this for a while and not sure how to check the password. This is what I have so far from a user submission:

```
if os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
    if ('user_pw' in request)  and request["user_pw"].value.strip != '':
    #user_pw must match password from above
        password == request["user_pw"].value
    else:
        errors.append('Password not correct')
```

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: `if the_submitted_password == "programmingisfun": ..` although it's a *very poor* password management strategy. Also, remember that `=` is *assignment/binding* while `==` is *equality* - check your code.

Comment: The line `password == request["user_pw"].value` doesn't do anything.. it evaluates to True or False, but isn't assigned to a variable so the value gets lost.

Comment: @SethMMorton Then will this work better? `if ('user_pw' in request)  and request["user_pw"].value.strip != '' and password == request["user_pw"].value:`

Comment: @user2246674 I totally agree its a bad password.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some hashing somewhere because that looks like it's being stored plain text unless the password variable is hashed.

Comment: @Supremekhaoz I'm not sure. This is just a homework assignment. Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh ok then. I'm gonna put it as an answer

Comment: What are you importing into this file? I don't know what framework you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

All the if statement is checking for is if 'user_pw' is in request or if it's not empty. But the `password ==request["user_pw"].value` part wouldn't return anything because it doesn't have a conditional. try putting if statement around it like so:

```
if os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
    if ('user_pw' in request)  and request["user_pw"].value.strip != '':
        #user_pw must match password from above
        if(password == request["user_pw"].value): 
            #success 
        else:
            errors.append('Password not correct')
    else:
        errors.append('You didn\'t input a password')
```

Note: I'm not sure about this last part but just in case.
Also, if that check doesn't work try printing the contents of `request["user_pw"].value` and if it has no value then try `value()`

Comment: I get a 500 internal server error when using this. I feel like this should be right, but I don't know...I tried it with `request["user_pw"].value()` and it still did not work.

Comment: Are you using django or something like that? and what could've caused it has to do with the server like a request or something.

Comment: No django. Just loading onto my school's server.

Comment: Is it returning some kind of error that could give me an idea?

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: I'm sorry that's all it says. Thank you for your help tho.

Comment: All I can say is check the log sorry I couldn't help anymore.

Comment: Did you change #success to do something? A 500 could be a *compile* error too. Try running your script from a command line and see if you get errors.

Comment: `errors.append('Password not correct')` IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: No it is the error you put I just moved it up to be with the other check instead of the check to see if string is empty. To get error from command line you would have to run it in the command line or terminal.

Comment: That is probably because you left the #success comment and it's expecting something there you need to put some kind of feedback.